# Is there a printf like function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a hackerRank THEPADS problem.

The question is query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in OCCUPATIONS. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:

There are a total of 2 doctors.

There are a total of 2 singers.

There are a total of 3 actors.

There are a total of 3 professors.

the occupations table goes like this

```
CREATE TABLE occupations(name varchar(100),Occupation varchar(100));
```

so how can i print this format is there any printf like function in mysql

Here is the image of the records present in occupations table:
[image: here is the image of the records present in occupations table]

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to print a string   " there are a total of  " and " s."  in the **select** clause.and i got it by **concat** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use concat method to append and group by and count function to get number for each occupation

```
SELECT "There are a total of ", count(OCCUPATION), concat(lower(occupation),"s.") FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY count(OCCUPATION), OCCUPATION ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify. There is sucha function and it's `SELECT`. You can print things like this:

```
SELECT "Hello world" as "";
```

or

```
SELECT "Hello world" as ""\G;
```

There is no way to remove the `:` prefix in the second case.